# How to efficiently read a large property as a pandas DataFrame using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, bigdata

I'm working on a project where I have a large dataset stored in a relational database, specifically a "PriceHistory" table containing historical stock prices. I also have a "Stocks" table that contains the different symbols, and a "Tag" table that I don't care to use the normal loading of SQLAlchemy, but the price history is very heavy, and probably best if I use pandas directly since I need it as a dataframe.

Here is my Stock model:

```py
class StockModel(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "stocks"
    __table_args__ = (Index("idx_stocks_id", "id"),)

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    symbol = Column(String(50))

    price_history = # Don't know what to do
    tags = relationship(
        "TagModel", secondary="stock_tag_mapping", back_populates="stocks", cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan"
    )
```

The columns in the price history table are:

- id: Integer, primary key
- stock_id: Integer, foreign key to the stocks table
- date: DateTime
- open: Float
- close: Float
- low: Float
- high: Float
- volume: Float

I need to efficiently read the price history property for all stocks as a pandas DataFrame. I'd prefer to use SQLAlchemy to do this, but I'm open to other suggestions.

My Stock Domain Entity looks Like this:

```py
class Stock:
    symbol: Symbol
    tags: List[Tag]
    price_history: pd.DataFrame
```

Additionally, I'd like to support efficient retrieval of a specific stock's price on a given date without having to load the entire DataFrame in my repository. For example, I want to be able to call a function like
`get_price_by_date(symbol, date).`

Additional information:

- The price history table is very large, with hundreds of thousands of rows.
- I need to read the price history property for all stocks, not just a subset.
- I need the price history property as a pandas DataFrame so that I can perform various calculations on it.

What's the best approach to achieve this efficiently, considering the size of the "PriceHistory" table and my requirements?

Comment: If efficiency is crucial, I would go directly with pandas solutions or pure query, e.g. using  [pandas.read_sql_table][1] or [pandas.read_sql][2]

  [1]: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_table.html
  [2]: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html#pandas.read_sql

Answer (score 1):

Pandas already support importing tables directly through sqlalchemy engine

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine  
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///database.db")  
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():  
    data = pd.read_sql_table("data", conn)
```

Refer for more info:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html#pandas.read_sql
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_table.html#pandas.read_sql_table